# Opc Ua client documentation

Tags: opc-ua

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, I couldn't think of any other StackExchange website to ask it.

Is there any available documentation for the .net Opc.Ua.Client and Opc.Ua.Core libraries from the OPC foundation?

Having to guess what a property / function do is really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official (GitHub) website for the .NET implementation of OPC UA can be found [here](http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NET/)

You will found there some documentation about the .NET and also the whole OPC UA Specifications

EDIT: The GitHub Profile of the OPC Foundation is also [here](https://github.com/OPCFoundation)

Comment: Wow, thank you! Wasted so much time looking for that